# pip not installing editable packages correctly on python3.8/ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to create a docker image with python 3.8 on top of the nvidia image nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu18.04.
I'm using

```
apt-get install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3-pip
python3.8 -m pip install -U pip
```

and then installing packages in the form

```
python3.8 -m pip install -e my_package
```

If I install in standard mode, this works fine, but in editable mode the egg link gets installed in `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, which python3.8 seems unable to find.

I can work around this problem using PYTHONPATH, but I'd really prefer to be able to install with pip instead.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.